# Streamlit deployment dependency issues

Tags: dependencies, wkhtmltopdf, streamlit, pdfkit, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy a python project I have created using Streamlit, I have several packages that only require a pip install including pdfkit. All of my packages are working correctly and I currently have them all in a requirements.txt file. However, pdfkit requires a brew install of wkhtmltopdf in order to run.

I'm not exactly sure how to get it to work on streamlit since this is my first project I'm deploying with it, is there any way I can include the wkhtmltopdf install in the requirements.txt or in another file or do I have to make a buildpack (I am not exactly sure if this will even work with streamlit)

Answer (score 1):

Streamlit Community Cloud supports adding [your dependencies](https://docs.streamlit.io/streamlit-community-cloud/get-started/deploy-an-app/app-dependencies#add-python-dependencies) via `pipenv`, `conda`, `pip`, or `poetry` – your best bet would probably be to find that same version of the package within one of those dependency managers. Otherwise, you can also deploy your app on a [platform other than Community Cloud](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/streamlit-deployment-guide-wiki/5099) that would enable you to use `brew`.